# Making a DataGrid Editable in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I was trying to make dataGrid1 editable.  I read that I can create a class instance to a List then assign it to DataGrid.ItemSource.  This might only be 2 lines of code but still hung up on how to do it with the below code. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
public class MyData
{
    public string street { set; get; }
    public string town { set; get; }
}

DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
col1.Binding = new Binding("name");
dataGrid1.Columns.Add(col1);
dataGrid1.Items.Add((new MyData() { street = "5th ave", town = "neverland"}));
```

OK thanks for any help. Still trying to get used to posting on stackoverflow.  Here is what I changed and it worked out for me.

```
List<MyData> MyListBox1 =new List<MyData>();
MyListBox1.Add(new MyData() { street = "5th ave", town = "neverland"}));
List<MyData> MyListBox1 =new List<MyData>();
```

I also had to add

> using System.Collections.Generic;

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?
In your XAML code

```
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Street" Binding="{Binding street}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Town" Binding="{Binding town}"/>  
            <!-- by defect is editable -->

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Town" Binding="{Binding town}" IsReadOnly="True"/>  
            <!-- Not editable -->

            ... more properties
         </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
```

In your class only binding a List(Any enumerable) with the DataGrid

```
      public MyClass
      {
           InitializeComponent();
           List<MyData> lstData = new List<MyData>();
           dataGrid1.ItemsSource = lstData;
      }
```

With that you can edit your DataGrid, every item will be added to the List

Comment: Thanks. I was staying away from the XAML just to see if I could do everything in code. I had to first assign a directive using System.Collections.Generic to use the list then had to define the List<MyData> 1stData or myList in my case as public in the main class structure. Lastly it wasn't refreshing on new additions so I had to run a dataGrid1.Items.Refresh() after the new items were added. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

make your ItemsSource as ObservableCollection to work perfectly 
ObservableCollection  itmSrcLevels = new ObservableCollection(ItemsSrc1);

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not assigning an `ItemsSource`, you add an item to the `Items` collection, that is a rather different thing to do.

*(Also, why are you binding to `name` if there is no such property?)*

Comment: Hmmm I kind of reworked the project.  I will show you what I wound up doing in the code below. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelDietz: Please above and not below, comments are ill fit for code.